# http and non-www redirect to https

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

okay. i freaking hate it. i've been trying to resolve this for hours but i still can't figure out was wrong or what i am missing.

i have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

it does redirects http request to https but
whenever i type domain.com it redirects to https://domain.com
which throws an ssl error that says:

This is probably not the site you are looking for!
You attempted to reach domain.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as www.domain.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of domain.com.

Comment: Do you have a valid signed ssl certificate from a CA? If so make sure it's installed correctly. Self signed certs won't work. Does it work if you use www? Many CA's will give you both domain.com and www.domain.com when purchasing a ssl cert so that both work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your ssl cert but this should work for you no matter if there is www/http or not.

Try this to always force www and https.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```